# Opening a batch file using SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Opening a batch file using SQL Server procedure....

For this, I took the example of opening a notepad. And able to open it with the following code :

```
start "c:\windows\system32" notepad.exe
--- saved as : note.bat
```

I tried to open it with following procedure :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[executebat]
as
begin
   EXEC master.dbo.xp_CMDShell 'D:\ducont\note.bat'
end
```

also I enabled the `xp_cmdshell` option with following code ::

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

But when I try to execute the procedure, it showing continuously

```
" Query Executing..."
```

and no output !!

Guide me if I went wrong anywhere .

Comment: Is your SQL Server running on the same machine as your other code?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer.  When you run xp_cmdshell it is creating a `shell` to do any work you ask it to.  Your bat file is running inside that shell, and will open notepad, again inside the shell.  You just won't be able to see it.  Since it's expecting input (and can't get any) you are stuck with the " Query Executing..."

There really isn't a good way to do what you are asking for other than possibly using CLR.  Unfortunately I don't know enough about it to say for certain one way or another.  There may be an easier way in SQL 2012 or 2014 but I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: Actually my task is to close a windows service using bat file, and this bat file is to be invoked by a sql procedure !!!

Comment: Assuming that the account that xp_cmdshell uses has permissions that should be doable.  Fair warning though it is probably going to require administrative access to the server.  Just remember that everything is happening in a "shell" that you don't have access to except through that single command.